# How to prove the limit is infinite

Tags: calculus, limits

One has $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n}=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(a_n-b_n)}=0$. Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{b_n}=\infty$.

My work

One has for any $M>0$, there exists $N>0$, for all $n\geq N$, $a_n>M$. One has for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $K>0$, for all $k\geq K$, $|a_k-b_k|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\infty$?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski. Corrected

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*.

We have
$|a_{n}-b_{n}| < 1$ for large $n$, implying that
$
|a_{n}| - |b_{n}| < 1
$
for large $n$,
implying that $|b_{n}| > |a_{n}| - 1$ for large $n$;
but $|a_{n}| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M\in \mathbb R^+$ be given.

Set $z_n=a_n-b_n$ so that $b_n=a_n-z_n.\ $Now choose $N\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $n>N\Rightarrow \vert z_n\vert <1 \ $and $a_n>M+1$. Then, $b_n>(M+1)-1=M$, which shows that $b_n\rightarrow \infty.$